# How to configure apt to trust CDs

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

The [debian secure apt page](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) states that apt can be configured to always trust files from a CD. However, I can't find documentation of *how* to do this configuration.

> It's also worth noting that newer versions of the Debian installer use the same signed Release file mechanism during their debootstrap of
>   the Debian base system, before apt is available, and that the
>   installer even uses this system to verify pieces of itself that it
>   downloads from the net. Also, Debian does not currently sign the
>   Release files on its CDs; apt can be configured to always trust
>   packages from CDs so this is not a large problem.

How do I configure apt to trust a CD?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`apt-cdrom`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList?action=show&redirect=sources.list#CD-ROM) or setup `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually.